# Edit Text During Google Slides Presentation

Tags: presentation, google-slides-api

I am trying to build a form in google slides. The form will have specific user inputs like first/last name, email, and zipcode. These inputs will be added to a google spreadsheet after the user submits. It isn't necessary that this happens at that time as most of the time, I will be using this form offline.

I do not wish to use google forms to avoid scrolling or single entry pages. The form would be one slide. How do I create a text box that is editable during a presentation?

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43463046/edit) the question to be on-topic: include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that duplicates the problem. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot edit when presenting, slides are just pictures/videos. You must go with Google Forms or make your own GUI.

Comment: Thanks! Further question about forms, is there a way to combine multiple question items? For example, a GridItem that includes a ListItem?